# A cartoon rebus

Tags: rebus

This is one of the many things I am bad at (amongst making up hard rebuses and thinking of creative ways to fill the character limit). What is it?

[image]

<sub>*Note that the hand cartoon in the image doesn't belong to me.</sub>

Comment: Aaaah I feel like I can get this one if I try and just think

Comment: And well done for getting to 1k rep

Comment: @Beastly Gerbil: Thanks. For those of you who are trying to solve this: My 'background story' is pretty bad and completely unhelpful considering the picture. Does this help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on the "simpler than that" from the comments, it could be

> Throw in G $\rightarrow$ Throwing

Comment: Close. This could've been the answer.

Comment: Any of the above?

Comment: Throwing is the answer I was thinking of. Looking at things, this could've been a triple rebus.

Comment: Wait, so there is a question_asker and a Question Asker?  Looks like Question Asker should consider a name change based on the join dates.

Comment: Given the nature of placement in rebuses, for this to be the correct answer, I would expect the hand-line-ball to exist *within* the confines of the letter.

Comment: @QuestionAsker And, a tip for the sake of future rebus making -- typically one would consider both the un-conjugated and gerund forms (among others) when assessing a pictorial verb, so the G isn't even necessary.  For a single word, pieces are better. e.g. [picture of a neck] - @ + [picture of a bird/bat/etc appendage] = THROAT - AT + WING = THROWING

Comment: Balling works too then

Comment: To be honest, I originally had this as an idea in mind for one of the rebuses in here: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30440/rebuses-linked-by-a-certain-topic. However, I realised that in football it was actually called "throw-in", instead of "throwing, as I had originally thought.

Answer (score 14):

Is it perhaps

> **GAMING**? $~~$(that is: **G** plus **aiming**)

Comment: Wow that's a nice idea. If I'd thought harder, I could've perhaps made this a double rebus. Unfortunately, this meaning wasn't my intention.

Comment: @Gamow congrats! First puzzler to reach 30k rep

Comment: By the way, this rebus is actually very simple, and the answer is right in front of you. I like your answer better ^^'.

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer

> G pitch,  looks like the hand is pitching a ball at the G, G pitch as in tuning

Comment: Nope, sorry. Simpler than that. Like I said to Gamow, the answer is right in front of you :)

Comment: @QuestionAsker Right in front of me is a picture of a hand throwing a ball at a G. So the answer is clearly "a picture of a hand throwing a ball at a G". :P

Answer (score 0):

> G for gravity and the ball moving  towards it...then is it gravity? But the ball is thrown upwards!!