# Rebuses linked by a certain topic

Tags: rebus, knowledge

See if you can solve these rebuses which range from easy to hard. They are all linked by a topic.

1. > On e
2. > luu (-4)
3. [image]
4. [image]
5. [image]

**EDIT:**

Hints:

> 2. I could have added a space to make it make easier.
>  4. Treat the 4+*image* as one unit. Keep reading it aloud.
>  5. rlord3534 has the interpretation for the 3 images correct. Now see if you can make sense of them. It would help if you keep thinking about what exactly you are trying to solve.

[Note that I have now posted the solutions to this puzzle below]

<sub>*Note the images of the flags, bus, spring, trophy outline and the text for 'tumn' do not belong to me (all obtained online).</sub>

Comment: Ok could you maybe give us a hint?

Comment: Does it have to do with an event?

Comment: Think I got 3... Are they all different sports?

Comment: For those who insist on trying to solve the hardest one without having got the easier ones, you'll know you have the answer when you have it. So stop wasting paper doing it :p

Comment: Update: I've commented above about number 5. So far, only number 1 and 3 have been solved. Congratulations to rlord3534 for getting 3!

Comment: Are 2 and 4 linked or can they be solved individually?

Comment: None of them are linked (other than by topic). They all can be solved individually.

Comment: last of 5- year?

Comment: No, sorry not year. I noted elsewhere in a comment that the arrows are the most important thing.

Comment: Update: I have added hints for 2, 4 and 5 as they aren't solved yet. I hope they help!

Comment: Another update: improved hint for 4. In addition, congratulations to Volatility for getting number 2. It was posted in a comment a few days ago which I didn't notice.

Comment: Given the number of attempts and amount of struggling involved in solving this (and there is still no complete answer), I'm tempted to say that this is only difficult because the answer is obscure, or the puzzle is poorly constructed. It is for this reason that I have downvoted.

Comment: I have not yet posted the answer yet, although I will in another few days. Please don't judge the puzzle until you see the answer - that is just unfair.

Comment: Update: I have now posted the solutions to the puzzles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that not all of them have been solved, and the solutions are scattered through several answers, I shall post the full solutions here.

1. Solver: This was solved quite quickly, and I cannot attribute anyone in particular with it (as several people got it).

   Quite literally:

   > A hole in one

---

Given the solution for 1, the topic is most likely to be (and is):

> Sports (although it actually is slightly more refined than this, as I have posted in the side note at the very bottom of this answer)

although some guessed that it might be:

> Golf

---

2. Solver: Volatility

   This was quite mean, and I could have made it easier to get by writing it as:

   > l uu (-4)

   Nevertheless, it's

   > l before double u $\to$ l b4 w $\to$
   >  lbw (cricket)

   The '-4' is optional, as

   > the b stands for 'before' anyway, hence the brackets.

---

3. Solver: rlord3534

   > [triangle] - [angle] = tri

   which sounds like:

   > Try (rugby)

---

4. Unsolved

   I could have perhaps made it easier by drawing the arrow in a more helpful place. However, the point of giving rebuses linked by a certain topic was so that solvers could try to 'guess' the solution by thinking of common phrases which I might have put in, and this was the case for this rebus.

   > In the hint, I said it would be helpful to consider the 4+*image* as one unit.
   >  The image represents the flags of the countries in the **uk**

   So that part of the rebus says:

   > 4 + uk $\to$ four add uk

   The arrow represents:

   > out

   So combining these, we get:

   > out four add uk

   Reading this out loud:

   > out four a-dduk (pronouncing uk as "uck" rather than "you kay")

   Which sounds like:

   > Out for a duck (cricket)

---

5. Partial solvers: rlord3534 (got all of the mini-rebuses), Aleeeeee (almost got there afterwards)

   First, get the interpretation of the 3 images:

   The first one wasn't hard:

   > Bus

   The second one was slightly harder, but was guessed by some:

   > u's (plural of the letter 'u')

   The third was made up of 4 images:

   > spring $\to$ Spring
   >  some 'er' $\to$ Summer
   >  gold 'tumn' $\to$ Au 'tumn' (chemistry) $\to$ Autumn
   >  win 'ter' $\to$ Winter

   So these 4 images represent:

   > the seasons

   However, this is not the correct interpretation for this final part, and I did say to some that the arrows were the most important.

   Note that we are trying to solve a rebus, and I underlined the importance of this in my hint.

   > The word ‘**re**bus’ is quite close to the first image, but with an extra ‘**re**’.
   >  If we apply this ‘**re**’ to the next image, we get ‘**re**[u’s]', which sounds like ‘**re**use’.
   >  This might lead to the interpretation of the final image which is ‘**cycle**’. If we add ‘**re**’ to it, we get ‘**re**cycle’.

   This now gives us:

   > **re**bus, **re**use, **re**cycle

   This is quite similar to the phrase:

   > reduce reuse recycle (which Aleeeeee managed to spot)

   Yet the key to solving this puzzle is:

   > The word 'reduce' is replaced with 'rebus'.
   >  This perhaps indicates that the solution of the original **rebus** is ‘reduce’.

   But this isn’t sports related, and that’s because:

   > The original rebus did not have any ‘**re**’s in it — they were placed there by us in order to help solve the puzzle. The image which would have completed the rebus (the image which should have replaced the ‘bus’), should’ve been ‘duce’, or something which sounded like that in order to complete the pattern.

   Therefore the final solution is:

   > re**duce** $\to$ duce

   Which sounds like:

   > Deuce (tennis)

   Side note:

   > The sport doesn’t have to be tennis, but it most often is associated with it. Note that the theme is more specifically terminology (words/phrases) used in sport.

Comment: I stand by my downvote. That last one is too convoluted and poorly constructed.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I disagree. It's convoluted, because I have to explain how to solve it rather than how to solve it. It certainly is not poorly constructed considering the layers of logic/puzzle I've put into it which is clear from my solution. It was not something which was thought up in a short time. Nevertheless, you can stand by your opinion.

Answer (score 11):

Incomplete answer?

> Looks like linked by sports.

Number 1:

> Hole in one. (Golf) *confirmed*

2:

> LBW (Cricket) -- L before double U -4(-fore) *confirmed*
>  Credit to Volatility

3:

> Triangle missing and angle is a try. (Rugby)  *confirmed*
>  Credit to rlord

4:

> Fork Upright? Possibly referencing bike racks or a goalpost?

5:

> Bus
>  U's
>  (Gold -au) tumn, spring, (win)ter, (summ)er. -> cycle.
>  Bus - u's + cycle = b cycle or bicycle.

Comment: Those blanks scared me, haha. Yes - correct for the first one, and the topic.

Comment: Think I got 3? But still could be wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Comment: in 5, the final image represents the 4 seasons (winter, spring, summer, autumn)

Comment: @rlord3534 I got that.

Comment: Correct - that's what the images represent. Unfortunately, the arrows are much more important than the 4 rebuses in that final image.

Comment: The last one is the hardest. I'm afraid not. (In addition, I'm not 100% satisfied with the explanation for the (summ)er rebus)

Comment: Stick to buses, not coaches. How did you get the summer? (Was it just deduced from the other 3?)

Comment: Yah. And ok I'll stick to buses.

Comment: I thought it was just "some 'er's"

Comment: @question_asker that's what I assumed.

Comment: Tour (bus) something year round

Comment: @QuestionAsker how's the answers looking now?

Comment: Still in the same position as before (only 1.). Only the first one is good. And I can assure you - my knowledge in golf is practically non-existent, so I'm unfamiliar with all of the other answers you've put.

Comment: 2 is LBW in cricket ('l' be(-fore) double 'u')

Comment: Is it worth thinking about sports which involve a 'fork' for #4? 4(four) + UK = fork?

Comment: @QuestionAsker so #2 isn't correct?

Comment: @SlashmanX I tried going that route the other day to no avail.

Comment: @Volatility - yes that is correct. I did not notice your comment. Did you post an answer somewhere else too? Sorry about that.

Comment: @QuestionAsker is #2 right? LBW?

Comment: @Z.Dailey, Yes - that is correct.

Comment: @QuestionAsker that's ok. Had no clue for the others so didn't think it was worth posting an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Incomplete:

> Sports

1

> Hole in one - Thanks to @Raystafarian

2

> lose by four?

3

> The triangle is missing one of its angles.  Therefore, by removing "angle" from "triangle" you are left with tri.  The answer is try, a term used for a score in rugby.

4.

> The four flags represent the united kingdom.  The arrow could be pointing norway/scandonavia? 4 + Norway

5.

> Another shot in the dark.  Bus + u's + cycle. Could possibly sound like bicycle.  Bicycle kick?

Comment: I'm thinking that too for 2, but still having a hard time with the answer.

Comment: I'm afraid the others had the theme right - my knowledge in sport kinda things is more general and thin. If you want to know how patchy my knowledge is: I had to google 'The masters' :p

Comment: Fair enough, figured it was worth a shot

Comment: Nice one! You have number 3 solved. The rest are off, I'm afraid.

Comment: Very nice! You have the interpretation of the 3 mini-rebuses correct for 5. But the whole rebus isn't solved yet..

Comment: I'm going to post a rebus with "Bus - u's + cycle" :)

Answer (score 3):

I may have part of the fifth. It's actually missing the connection with the topic....
Thanks to rlord3534 for the interpretation and to the OP for the hint :)

5:

> Reduce reuse recycle
>  Cycle bus and u's = Re-bus re-use
>  If you want to cycle cycle, there's also re-cycle
>  Rebus sounds like reduce

Comment: You are inches away. Keep staring at the first line you have written in your answer and see how it relates with the interpretation of the images. I can assure you the answer is related to sport. Not everything has to be included in the final answer.

Comment: I've awarded the bounty to this answer, as it is pretty much there, although incorrect, and the bounty has expired. See if you can still get it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Trying again for the unsolved ones:

2

> ?

4

> 4 in a row?

5

> Musical? (Taking the B from bus, "use", "cycle") sounds like "Musical"

Comment: I'm afraid not. You'll have to think harder for this one as it's not so simple.

Comment: @QuestionAsker I gave it another go. How did I do?

Comment: Still no, I'm afraid. Others have been slightly more successful.

Comment: @QuestionAsker haha no worries. I am new to Rebus puzzles so going to fail hard at them :D

Answer (score 0):

Topic:

> Golf

1:

> Hole in 1

2:

> Lose the albatross?

3:

> The Open

4:

> Scotland win the foursomes?

5:

> Double decker (driving ranges) ooze all year round

Probably not all correct, but worth a shot.

Comment: I had originally put the masters as my answer but, it was clarified that the theme is just sports in general

Comment: Nope - only hole in 1 is correct.